# Create a DMG from my external hard drive for backup purpose

Tags: backup, external-hard-drive, dmg-image

I would like to know how it is possible to create a DMG image from my external hard drive to copy it to another hard drive as a double backup. I was having a look around but didn't really came to the conclusion how to manage this the proper way.

I'm on a Mac OSX El Capitan and I'm happy to use any CLI utilities

Many thanks

Comment: Why not just configure TimeMachine? It'll do your whole OS disk; and multiple copies at that (different times).

Comment: @BigChris because I'm not trying to backup my whole OS disk, but duplicate an external hard drive.